# Animation in Unity look different than in Blender - rigify addon

Tags: animation, export, unity, .fbx, rigify

I am working on a school project and need to import this simple model and animation of a crane to Unity. It was made using a Rigify rig. In Blender the animation looks like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnPaE.jpg
And in Unity it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wyi9D.jpg

The difference is in how the left wing and the head are distorted in some parts of the animation. It happens when I export in .fbx and also when I import a .blend file to Unity.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have stretched the wing/neck and that's where the exported animation looks different.
Try to avoid squashing or stretching the bones and the problems should be fixed.

If you have an hour or so I have a video that explains why this happens. I recommend watching the whole thing but the squash/stretch problem is covered around 39:32
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Xm1h700uhk

Comment: This helped me so much! Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear that :)